# Insertar "n" registros con un procedimiento ,workbench mysql

Tags: mysql

Necesito ayuda.

Nos han pedido en un ejercicio del grado insertar 10000 registros al mismo tiempo en una tabla  ,tengo la intuición que me falta un último paso pero no logro dar con el .

MI idea es crear una tabla simple como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla stock_semillas contiene estos campos

Cod_semilla , Nombre

**La tabla creada**

```
*Create table stock_semillas(Codigo int not null primary key, Nombre varchar(15);*
```

**y Este es el procedimiento que estoy elaborando**

```
*DELIMITER |
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXIsTS n_registros;

CREATE PROCEDURE n_registros()

begin
DECLARE n int ;                
set n = 1 ;                 
while n <= 10000 do            
insert into stock_semillas values (n, 'Nombre' + convert(varchar(15));                
select n = n + 1 ;                 
end while;

END|

DELIMITER ;*
```

He conseguido colar el procedimiento sin el convert pero al lanzar la llamada workbench me devuelve que el codigo semilla el cual es clave principal , se repite .

**el error que me da workbench don el código expuesto:**

Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now

lo curioso es que workench no me avisa de ningun error dentro de el còdigo ..

Comment: Hola! Por favor no resumas el error; ve a [edit] y añade el mensaje de error completo

Comment: convert(varchar(15)); que quiere decir???

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que la función **CONVERT** no esta escrita correctamente, **hace falta la expresión en la función**, en este caso el parámetro "n".

Un ejemplo que te recomiendo para solucionarlo es lo siguiente:

```
INSERT INTO stock_semillas VALUES (n, 'Nombre' + CAST(n AS VARCHAR(15));
```

Lo que sucede en esta linea es que insertas el valor n (contador) y el nombre concatenado junto al contador, viendo un resultado como este:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: gracias por el interes eekJaaj , pero he probado el código introduciendo tu variante y me devuelve el mismo error descrito arriba para workbench "Error Code: 2014 Commands out of sync; you can't run this command now"

Answer (score 0):

El problema de los bucles y, aún más, de las inserciones individuales, es que son extremadamente lentos. Te propongo otra solución mucho más eficiente, porque realiza las inserciones en bloque.

Comenzamos creando la tabla e insertando un par de registros:

```
CREATE TABLE stock_semillas(
  codigo int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  nombre varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO stock_semillas (nombre) VALUES
('Nombre1'),('Nombre2');
```

Con estos dos registros ya podremos plantear un producto cartesiano e insertar 2^n registros en cada `INSERT` tal que así:

```
set @i:=(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM stock_semillas);
INSERT INTO stock_semillas
SELECT @i:=@i+1,CONCAT('Nombre',@i) nombre
  FROM stock_semillas n1,stock_semillas n2,stock_semillas n3,
  stock_semillas n4,stock_semillas n5,stock_semillas n6,
  stock_semillas n7,stock_semillas n8,stock_semillas n9,
  stock_semillas n10,stock_semillas n11,stock_semillas n12,
  stock_semillas n13,stock_semillas n14
  LIMIT 9998;
```

Obteniendo:

```
+--------+-------------+
| codigo | nombre      |
+--------+-------------+
|  10000 | Nombre10000 |
|   9999 | Nombre9999  |
|   9998 | Nombre9998  |
|   9997 | Nombre9997  |
|    ... |        ...  |
+--------+-------------+
```

Para saber cuántas veces tienes que multiplicar la tabla por sí misma, tienes que calcular el logaritmo en base 2
(o del número de registros que tengas inicialmente en la tabla) del número de nuevos registros que quieras insertar:

```
SELECT CEIL(LOG2(10000));
```

Que, para 10000, te dará 14.

Si partes de 6 registros en vez de 2, aplicando las propiedades de los logaritmos:

```
SELECT CEIL(LOG2(10000)/LOG2(6));
```

Únicamente tendrías que multiplicar 6 tablas. Eso sí, recuerda cambiar el `LIMIT 9998` a 9994, que son 10000 registros menos los 6 que ya tienes.

Comment: mE ha funcionado la inserción , eso si , se me ha olvidado comentar en mi enunciado que lo que busca la tarea es una inserción que provoque lentitud en el sistema . asi que la primera opcion no seria mala . Dicho esto probaré con la tuya David

Comment: ¿Te han pedido explícitamente una inserción que provoque lentitud en el sistema? Tal vez sea para luego explicarte que eso no es lo deseable :)

Comment: efectivamente , el tema trata de optimizar el servidor mysql . Se trata de una comprobación para que veamos que las consultas pueden alargarse si se producen en un sistema saturado . Funciona perfectamente tu código , gracias por la atención David

Comment: Genial, entonces [Recuerda validar y votar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) y [Gana +2 de reputación](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3762/119615)